# Does external schema count in Redshift Quota for Schema which is 9,900?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

As seen here the maximum number of schema in Redshift is 9,900. But does Redshift Spectrum count towards this ?

- [Quotas and limits in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html)
- [GitHub: Quotas and limits in Amazon Redshift](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-redshift-management-guide/blob/master/doc_source/amazon-redshift-limits.md)